# What are derivations on vector bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

A derivation on an $R$-algebra $A$ is an $R$-linear map $d:A\rightarrow A$ such that, the following condition is satisfied:
$$d(ab)=d(a)b+ad(b)$$
for all $a,b\in A$.

Given a manifold $M$, a derivation on $M$ is a derivation on the $\mathbb{R}$ -algebra $C^\infty(M)$, of smooth functions on $M$.

Then there is notion of derivation of vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$, which is defined to be a map of sections $\Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$ satisfying certain conditions.

When we take the trivial vector bundle $M\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$, the set of sections $\Gamma(M, M\times \mathbb{R})$ is precisely the smooth maps. Though $\Gamma(M, E)$ would not be an algebra.

So, the idea of taking sections looks fair. But, I don't fully understand the point. Any clarification regarding this would be useful.

Comment: There are some relations with zeroth order, first order differential operators on vector bundles. Any suggestions/references would be helpful..

Comment: You may be looking for the notion of [affine connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection)? It is a way to derive sections of a vector bundle with respect to tangent vectors.

Comment: @Didier Can you please elaborate why you think so. I know what an affine connection is (to some extent).. But, could not see how this question is related to affine connection

Comment: Well, it is hard to tell exactly what your question is since you say "there is a notion" without even defining it. Regarding affine connections: given a vector field $X$ and a connection $D$, the operation $D_X$ is a derivation of the tensor algebra associated to the considered vector bundle.

Comment: Can you be specific? As of now, it is not even clear which objects you have doubt with.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2100590/173147